# Combination problem: random selection in a group

Tags: random-variables, combinations, correlation, covariance

A scientific committee of 4 persons is to be randomly selected from a group consisting of 3 biologists, 3 physicists and 4 mathematicians. Let X denote the number of biologists, Y the number of physicists and Z the number of mathematicians on the committee.

What is the the joint probability mass function of the random vector *(X,Y,Z)* ?

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you're just posting a homework problem without any work towards an answer. Also, is this homework? If so please label it as such.

Comment: This is a sample problem, I'm studying for an exam. I don't exactly know where to start. I have tried fiddling around with combination formulas and PMF formulas but I'm not sure where to start. I'd really just appreciate a hint on the first question

Comment: Do I need to compute the average number of biologists chosen, physicists chosen, and mathematicians chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to put this in a comment. I am currently working on this problem as part of a problem set, but I would suggest the following: In order to find the joint probability mass function of a vector we can follow the chain rule of random variables. The chain rule of random variables with regards to the joint probability mass function for discrete values is as follows in the general form:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/2/2/8/228bdd2e47a40ce7b534b4f4680f10dc.png]

Which can be found on the wikipedia page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution

While this isn't a thorough answer, I hope it benefits you forming a proper approach.